# octave - What's a simple way to get a summary of a structure?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, octave

When loading different scientific datasets in Octave/MATLAB, the first thing I have to do, usually, is figure out how the data was organized (it's always different). Typically they come in a huge structure with a few different members. I'd like to find their names, dimensions, and types. A one-liner would be preferable.

An example structure is

ddata:

- ddata.sig, size 350x120x280, numeric
- ddata.prd, size 350x280, numeric
- ddata.labels size 1x280, binary

As an example of a summary function, R has a pretty useful function `summary()` (although it doesn't give dimensions):

```
> summary(filedatas[[1]])
    Length   Class  Mode   
cnt 35218280 -none- numeric
nfo        5 -none- list   
mrk        3 -none- list
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of dataset you're loading into Octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as easy as it seems. Note that a struct can be a struct array, and each field may have a different data type for each struct. How would your `summary` function behave in such case?

For example:

```
struct ("field1", {"text", 90}, "field2", {{1:3, "more"}, struct()})
```

That said, Octave has some functions to define how structs get displayed, `print_struct_array_contents` and `struct_levels_to_print`, see [its manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Usage-and-Examples.html).

Comment: is there a startup file I can get those set in, like a `.octave`?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander yes. You can set up an `.octaverc` file on your home directory which is executed at the start of each Octave session. I use it to create a function named man which is a wrapper to help, set colors to the prompt, the default figure position, etc

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `whos` and `disp` are the closest to what you're after - `disp` can be invoked just by typing the variable name alone. For scalars and matrices it displays the contents, but for structures you get a field summary. Here's an example using the first random dataset I could lay my hands on:

```
octave-3.6.4.exe:3> load ax204.mat
octave-3.6.4.exe:4> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name         Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====         ====                     =====  =====
        dc           1x1                        119  struct
        index        1x989                     7912  double
        objects      1x989                 15998424  struct

Total is 1979 elements using 16006455 bytes

octave-3.6.4.exe:5> dc
dc =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    fps =  2
    hdr =
    {
      [1,1] = Frame
      [1,2] = Time
      [1,3] = Speed
      [1,4] = X Cent
      [1,5] = Y Cent
      [1,6] = Length
      [1,7] = AvgWid
      [1,8] = Peri
      [1,9] = Round
    }
    f =  1
    t =  2
    x =  4
    y =  5
    l =  6
    aw =  7
    p =  8
    r =  9

octave-3.6.4.exe:6> objects
objects =

  1x989 struct array containing the fields:

    id
    data
    n
    dir
    dist
    turn
    reversals
    merge
    omg
    rev
    defrev
    begfr
    endfr
    previd
    begtm
    endtm
    begxpos
    endxpos
    begypos
    endypos
    xcent
    ycent
    spd
    db
    ab
```

If a structure field is nonscalar, IIRC Matlab is sensible and says something like `fieldname: [200x300 double]`, whereas Octave merrily dumps the entire contents.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a 'summary'. Try invoking the name of a structure with a ton of data points in its members like the one I mentioned in the question ;)

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Unfortunately that's pretty much the limit of the Matlab built-ins - summarising workspace variables and dumping structure fields. There's code out there for pretty-printing structures, but it's typically dozens of lines.